# TwinCAT: Running on isolated cores failed

Tags: plc, twincat

I was trying to activate my configuration on my local PC, but it failed. I tried:

1. Isolate 1 or 2 cores on my pc (Under SYSTEM > Real-Time and reboot the PC) and run the PLC tasks on those cores. When I do this I get the following error:

> 'TwinCAT System' (10000): Sending ams command >> Init4\RTime: Start Interrupt: Ticker started >> AdsWarning: 4118 (0x1016, RTIME: startup of isolated CPU fails!) << failed!

[image: AdsWarning: 4118 (0x1016, RTIME: startup of isolated CPU fails!)]

2. I then tried to run it on the normal windows dedicated CPUs (so none of the CPU’s were isolated). When I activated the configuration (and enabled Virtualization in the BIOS) I got the following error message:

> Setting TwinCAT in Run Mode with KB4056894 is not possible
>
> Uninstall KB4056894
>
> or
>
> Activate a solution using only isolated cores

[image: Setting TwinCAT in Run MOde with KB4056894 is not possible]

I could not find KB4056894 installed on my PC. Any other solution?

I'm using TwinCAT 3 Build 4022.14 under Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Beckhoff support:

> According to the error note, the Microsoft patch for spectre/meltdown
>   is installed on your PC. Normally, the TC3 should work with this patch
>   when using isolated cores…
>
> However, since version TC3 Build 4022.16, this problem is solved.

I installed 4022.22 and everything worked.

Comment: Nice to known that 4022.22 solves this. If this the final matter in this question, you're welcome to accept your own answer.

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus too bad there’s so little info on Beckhoff errors online.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my experience with this error and how I solved it. Just in real-time menu set the cpu cores as 1 shared and 3 isolated cores. since my cpu has 4 core. Then set this value on target and then it will ask for reboot. after reboot it worked without this error and I was able to run the my code.