# TwinCAT3: Running on isolated cores failed

Tags: plc, twincat

I'm using`twincat3.1.4020.32` on `windows10`.
I've tried one simple code as: `i:= i+1;`

but I got following error:

'TwinCAT System' (10000): Sending ams command >> Init4\RTime: Start Interrupt: Ticker started >> AdsWarning: 4118 (0x1016, RTIME: startup of isolated CPU fails!) << failed!

[image]

I've tried to solve this but It didn't work at all. I found same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185052/twincat-running-on-isolated-cores-failed) but I'm using `twincat3.1.4020.32` as I said at the first of my question.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the problem was solved in Build 4022.16, so you need to install a version later than that.

If you really need to stick with Build 4020.32 for compatibility reasons, there was a fix at the time in the registration database. I can't remember it now, but your local Beckhoff support should be able to help you.